# NiceScroll not showing on click event

Tags: jquery, nicescroll

I have a toggle button that show a side menu.

The side menu have a niceScroll.

I try hide niceScroll on hide menu event and that's working and I can see the cursor(niceScroll bar). Now on show menu event I try to show niceScroll and It's working but the cursor still hide.

I'm using this code for hide niceScroll at "hide menu event":

```
$("#sidebar").getNiceScroll().hide()
```

And this code to show niceScroll at "show menu event":

```
$("#sidebar").getNiceScroll().show()
```

any help please

**Update**

when I try to show it by clicking on menu, the css is:

```
left:-6px
```

I think it's a bug, didn't it ?

here is [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/xgzm1ctg/)

Comment: did you try move the hide/show to where sidebar collapse "shown" or "hide" functions is instead?

Comment: There is no event for sidebar collapse. in my code the collapse events not for sidebar toggle. these events for sidebar items (items that have a childs)

Comment: yes there is... $('.sidebar .collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () { <-- that's the code that checks if the sidebar has collapsed or the other one, hidden;

Comment: @zerohero . this code for side bar items. please refer to my example above and see menu items. you'll notice "Products". the collapse code for like this items

Answer (score 1):

here is [my solution](https://jsfiddle.net/mustint/xgzm1ctg/3/) based on this [issue solution](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/398)

I used `remove` instead of `hide` like this:

```
$("#sidebar").getNiceScroll().remove();
```

and I move the niceScroll initial from `document.ready` to a function `callNiceScroll()` and at the menu show event I call it with timeout:

```
setTimeout(callNiceScroll, 400);
```

and now it's working

Comment: That's exactly what I suggested, to move the call to nice scroll to the menu show or hide event; $('.sidebar .collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {

Comment: @zerohero . you should be more clear. however you give me the idea. thanks